# Custom ArrayAdapter AutoCompleteTextView not triggering

Tags: android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

Custom ArrayAdapter AutoCompleteTextView not triggering 
I’m trying to use a AutoCompleteTextView with a ArrayList of objects using a custom list adapter and I cannot get the auto complete list to display.  Here is my code:
activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="rick.customarrayadpter.MainActivity">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/customerACTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="search" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

MainActivity.java
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ArrayList<Customer> customerList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
            customerList.add(new Customer(111, "Pete"));
            customerList.add(new Customer(222, "Bob"));
            customerList.add(new Customer(333, "Paul"));
            customerList.add(new Customer(444, "Tom"));
            customerList.add(new Customer(555, "Jane"));
            customerList.add(new Customer(666, "Susan"));

            CustomerListAdapter customerListAdapter = new CustomerListAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, R.id.customerACTV, customerList);
            AutoCompleteTextView customerACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.customerACTV);
            customerACTV.setThreshold(1);
            customerACTV.setAdapter(customerListAdapter);

        }

    }

CustomerListAdapter.java
    public class CustomerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Customer> {

            ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();

            public CustomerListAdapter(Context context, int resource,int textViewResourceId,  ArrayList<Customer> objects) {
                super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
                customerList = objects;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return super.getCount();
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View v = convertView;
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
                AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.customerACTV);
                textView.setText(customerList.get(position).getName());
                return v;

            }
        }

list_items.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:text="Demo"
            android:textColor="#000" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    Customer.java
    public class Customer {
        String name;
        int id;
        public Customer(int ID, String Name){
            this.id = ID;
            this.name = Name;
        }

        public String getName(){return this.name;}
        public int getId(){return this.id;}
    }
```

There is no errors in the code but it does not show the auto complete selection when I enter letters in the customerACTV. The CustomerListAdapter constructor is getting called and the ArrayList of the Customer objects is getting passed but the getView of the CustomerListAdapter is not getting called.

Thanks

Comment: I've seen some other postings with this same problem but no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For auto suggestions to work, in autocomplete textview, we have to over-ride `getFilter()`, where we set the filter functionality, the default adapter can only filter strings, and you are using an object `Customer`

So you need to do the following in you :

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return new Filter() {
        final Object object = new Object();

        @Override
        public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
         return resultValue.toString();

        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {




            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint != null) {

                for (Customer customer : customerList) {
                    if (department instanceof SearchableStrings) {
                        if (customer.getname().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                            customers.add(customer);

                        }

                    } 
                    if (customers.size() > 1) {
                        filterResults.values = customers;
                        filterResults.count =      customers.size();
                    } else {
                        filterResults.values = null;
                        filterResults.count = 0;


                }



            }
            //notifyDataSetChanged();
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            // mObjects.clear();
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
               clear();
                // avoids unchecked cast warning when using customerList.addAll((ArrayList<Customer>) results.values);
                for (Object object : (List<?>) results.values) {
                    add(object);


                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }


    };
```

Comment: Thanks Kaustubh, That was the problem and it is working now but I still have a little problem. When I select something from the dropdown list of the autocomplete and then use the backspace key or change the text the autocomplete dropdown does not show. If a user want to change there selection it should show again. Any suggestions?  Thanks again.

Comment: I can only see the adapter, and it looks good, autocomplete drop box does not show up only if you have nothing in the publishresults method, please debug and check it

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Customer> {

ArrayList<Customer> customerList, suggestionList;


public CustomerListAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Customer> customerList) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, customerList);
    this.customerList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.customerList = customerList;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
    }

    Customer customer = customerList.get(position);
    if(customer != null){
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if(textView != null)
            textView.setText(customer.getName());
    }
    return view;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        final Object object = new Object();

        @Override
        public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            Customer customer = (Customer) resultValue;
            return customer.getName();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {


            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            suggestionList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (constraint != null) {
                for (Customer customer : customerList) {

                    if (customer.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        suggestionList.add(customer);
                    }
                    if (customerList.size() > 1) {
                        filterResults.values = suggestionList;
                        filterResults.count = suggestionList.size();
                    } else {
                        filterResults.values = null;
                        filterResults.count = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults (CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results){
            ArrayList<Customer> filterList = (ArrayList<Customer>)results.values;

            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (Customer customer : filterList) {
                    add(customer);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: I found a couple of problems when debugging it. The getFilter performFiltering function had to be changed and the CustomerListAdapter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

public class CustomerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private ArrayList<Customer> customerList;
private ArrayList<Customer> filteredList;

public CustomerListAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Customer> customerList) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, customerList);
    this.customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>(customerList);
    this.filteredList = customerList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
    }

    Customer customer = filteredList.get(position);
    if(customer != null){
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if(textView != null)
            textView.setText(customer.getName());
    }
    return view;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        final Object object = new Object();

        @Override
        public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            Customer customer = (Customer) resultValue;
            return customer.getName();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<Customer> filters = new ArrayList<Customer>();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length()>0) {
                for (Customer customer : customerList) {

                    if (customer.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        filters.add(customer);
                    }
                 }
                filterResults.values = filters;
                filterResults.count = filters.size();
                filteredList = filters;
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults (CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results){
            ArrayList<Customer> filterList = (ArrayList<Customer>)results.values;

            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (Customer customer : filterList) {
                    add(customer);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: In the constructor, I had customerList = objects; which sets the variable customerList to the same reference as objects. So, if I modified any of the objects items it changed the customerList items as well, and the base class must have been changing them. So I changed it to this.customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>(customerList); This keeps a copy of the original ArrayList use in the performFiltering when the selection is changed like by the backspace key. 
Thanks for helping Kaustubh. I was really stuck on that one.